# How to use rxNetty client with EmbeddedChannel for testing

Tags: rx-java, rx-netty

Given that I have `TcpClient` like this:

```
TcpClient.newClient(...)
         .pipelineConfigurator(...)
         .createConnectionRequest()
         .flatMap(c -> c.getInput())
```

I would like to test it using Netty's `EmbeddedChannel` to simulate the interactions between the server and the client and make assertions on both `EmbeddedChannel` and `TestSubscriber`.

I am struggling to find a way of passing `EmbeddedChannel` to achieve this. I was looking at `channelProvider()` to do it like this:

```
EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel()
ChannelPorivderFactory providerFactory = (a,b,c,d) -> n -> Observable.just(channel);

TestSubscriber<Object> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

TcpClient.newClient(...)
         .pipelineConfigurator(...)
         .channelProvider(providerFactory)
         .createConnectionRequest()
         .flatMap(c -> c.getInput())
         .subscribe(subscriber);

embeddedChannel.writeInbound(serverMessage);
subscriber.assertValueCount(1);
```

I can now `channel.writeInbound(someServerResponse)` and I can see in Netty wire logs the bytes are written but I am getting this message

`Data received on channel, but no subscriber registered. Discarding data.`

I am defo writing the data AFTER subscription

what am I missing?

Comment: I'm going to guess that `subscriber` receives message on the inbound path, so `writeOutbound()` sends messages the wrong way. You can check the direction explicitly by adding two channel handlers to the pipeline that log their input.

Comment: @BobDalgleish good catch! Though it doesn't work either what I see now is this message from rxNetty: `Data received on channel, but no subscriber registered. Discarding data.` Though I am writing to `EmbeddedChannel` after subscription....

Comment: @BobDalgleish. I've edited the question to reflect this

Comment: You have left out all of the details, particularly the `flatMap()` transformation. I suspect right now that your `flatMap()` doesn't map the connection request into a data stream.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I updated the question that simply shows that the `flatMap()` should pass down the stream anything coming out of Netty's pipeline, but still rxNetty discards the message cause it thinks nothing is subscribed... I think that my way of passing the EmbeddedChannel may not fully hook it up with rxNetty's internals. Documentation is scarce, so I am walking in the dark a bit here

Comment: Updated the question to show the assertion I am trying to make

Comment: BTW, it works fine when running against real server, data flows and all is great, I am just having troubles to write tests